# Angular - fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(IsRouteDirective) can't find host element

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-directive

I'm writing tests for a directive but I can't get the query for the directive host element to work using `By.directive(IsRouteDirective)`. Console logging `hostElement` always yields `null`.

In the code below, `LibRouteComponent` and `LibTestComponent` are just dummy components with an empty template.

Here's the directive (short version):

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[libIsRoute]'
})

export class IsRouteDirective implements OnInit { ... }
```

And here's the test setup for it:

```
describe('IsRouteDirective', () => {

  let directive: IsRouteDirective;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<LibTestComponent>;
  let hostElement;

  beforeEach(() => {

    fixture = TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        LibTestModule,
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([
          {
            path: '',
            pathMatch: 'full',
            redirectTo: 'foo'
          },
          {
            path: 'foo',
            component: LibRouteComponent
          },
          {
            path: 'bar',
            component: LibRouteComponent
          }
        ])
      ],
      declarations: [IsRouteDirective]
    })
    .overrideComponent(LibTestComponent, {
      set: {
        template: `
          <router-outlet></router-outlet>
          <div [libIsRoute]="['foo']"></div>
        `
      }
    })
    .createComponent(LibTestComponent);

    fixture.detectChanges();

    hostElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(IsRouteDirective));
    console.log(hostElement);
    directive = hostElement.injector.get(IsRouteDirective);

  });

  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(hostElement).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Using `By.css('div')` gives `DebugElement{nativeNode: <div libisroute=""></div>....` in the log which shows that the element exists and the directive selector is set on it.

I'm doing exactly what the offical docs are doing [here](https://angular.io/guide/testing#attribute-directive-testing).

Why doesn't `By.directive(IsRouteDirective)` work in my case?

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I am having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

**WORKAROUND**

`fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(IsRouteDirective)).injector.get(IsRouteDirective)`

Answer (score 0):

In my case I simply forgot to add the TestComponent to declarations of the TestBed module. It still allowed me to call `createComponent(TestComponent)` for it but wasn't able to query any components from its template